# How to divide after grouping two different metrics in Prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm currently trying to alert on Kubernetes pods stacking within an availability zone. I've managed to use two different metrics to the point where I can see how many pods for an application are running on a specific availability zone. However, due to scaling, I want the alert to be percentage based...so we can alert when a specific percentage of pods are running on one AZ (i.e. over 70%).

My current query:

```
sum(count(kube_pod_info{namespace="somenamespace", created_by_kind="StatefulSet"}) by (created_by_name, node) * on (node) group_left(az_info) kube_node_labels) by (created_by_name, az_info)
```

And some selected output:

```
{created_by_name="some-db-1",az_info="az1"} 1
{created_by_name="some-db-1",az_info="az2"} 4
{created_by_name="some-db-2",az_info="az1"} 2
{created_by_name="some-db-2",az_info="az2"} 3
```

For example, in the above output we can see that 4 db-1 pods are stacking on az2 as opposed to 1 pod on az1. In this scenario we would want to alert as 80% of db-1 pods are stacked on a single AZ.

As the output contains multiple pods on multiple AZs, it feels like it may be difficult to get the percentage using a single Prometheus query, but wondered if anyone with more experience could offer a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  your_expression 
/ ignoring(created_by_name) group_left
  sum without(created_by_name)(your_expression)
```

will give you the ratio of the whole for each, and then you can do `> .8` on that.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me a whole lot closer. I believe that now gives me the sum of  db specific pods in an AZ (what I want), but divided by the total of pods (not what I want as it's not specific to a db) running in an AZ. Where as I need to divide the first part by just the total of db specific pods (e.g. 2 some-db-1 running in AZ1 divided by the total number of some-db-1 pods (let's say theres 5 in total) would mean 2/5 or 40%).

Comment: Managed to do it with: `sum(count(kube_pod_info{namespace="somenamespace", created_by_kind="StatefulSet"}) by (created_by_name, node) * on (node) group_left(zone) kube_node_labels) by (created_by_name, zone) / ignoring(zone) group_left sum without(zone)(sum(count(kube_pod_info{namespace="somenamespace", created_by_kind="StatefulSet"}) by (created_by_name, node) * on (node) group_left(zone) kube_node_labels) by (created_by_name, zone))`. Thank you, never would have got there otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

By default Prometheus divides time series pairs with identical sets of labels on the left and the right side of `/` operator. If time series on the left side of `/` contain two labels such as `created_by_name` and `zone`, while time series on the right side of `/` contain only a single label such as `created_by_name`, the Prometheus would return an empty result, since it won't find time series pairs with identical sets of labels for the division. This can be fixed by using `on()` and `group_left()` modifiers - the `on()` modifier limits the set of labels, which are taken into account during searching for time series pairs. The `group_left()` modifier allows matching multiple time series with the given `on()` labelset on the left side of `/` with a single time series with the same `on()` labelset on the right side of `/`. See more details [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).

So the resulting query, which divides each time series with a pair of `(created_by_name, zone)` labels by a sum time series with the matching `created_by_name` label would look like the following:

```
sum(q) by (created_by_name, zone)
  / on(created_by_name) group_left()
sum(q) by (created_by_name)
```

Where `q` must be substituted with the original query `count(kube_pod_info{namespace="somenamespace", created_by_kind="StatefulSet"}) by (created_by_name, node) * on (node) group_left(zone) kube_node_labels`.

The query can be simplified to the following one by using [WITH expressions](https://play.victoriametrics.com/promql/expand-with-exprs) from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html):

```
with (
  q = count(
    kube_pod_info{namespace="somenamespace", created_by_kind="StatefulSet"}
  ) by (created_by_name, node)
    * on (node) group_left(zone)
  kube_node_labels
)
sum(q) by (created_by_name, zone)
  / on(created_by_name) group_left()
sum(q) by (created_by_name)
```