# How to divide "sum()" by "count()" without labels

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have the CPU usage of a number of containers in percent of their respective container instance and I want to divide this value by the number of container instances available.

This query gives me as expected the CPU usage in percent:

```
sum by (name) (
  rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{$default, promstack_alias=~"$promstack_alias"}[$__rate_interval]) 
  * 100
)
```

And this query gives me nothing more than the number of instances:

```
count(sum by (instance_id) (container_last_seen{$default, instance_state="running"}))
```

But I am not able to combine them. What I want is basically this:

```
sum by (name) (
  rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{$default, promstack_alias=~"$promstack_alias"}[$__rate_interval]) 
  * 100
)
/
count(sum by (instance_id) (container_last_seen{$default, instance_state="running"}))
```

If I divide by a number, for example `3`, the query succeeds. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here [How to divide after grouping two different metrics in Prometheus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184167/how-to-divide-after-grouping-two-different-metrics-in-prometheus)

The key is to ignore existing labels with `/ ignoring(name) group_left`(in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus provides the following ways to divide time series with labels by time series without labels:

1. By wrapping the time series without labels into [scalar()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#scalar) function:

```
sum by (name) (
  rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{$default, promstack_alias=~"$promstack_alias"}[$__rate_interval]) 
  * 100
)
/
scalar(count(sum by (instance_id) (container_last_seen{$default, instance_state="running"})))
```

This enables division by scalar according to [these rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators).

2. By adding `on() group_left()` modifiers to `/`:

```
sum by (name) (
  rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{$default, promstack_alias=~"$promstack_alias"}[$__rate_interval]) 
  * 100
)
/ on() group_left()
count(sum by (instance_id) (container_last_seen{$default, instance_state="running"}))
```

This enables many-to-one matching for time series on the left and the right side of `/` operator according to [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches).